# R's equivalent of Python's re.findall

Tags: python, r, regex

I am trying to get all matches for a RegExp from a string but apparently it's not so easy in R, or I have overlooked something. Truth be told, it's really confusing and I found myself lost among all the options: `str_extract`, `str_match`, `str_match_all`, `regexec`, `grep`, `gregexpr`, and who knows how many others.

In reality, all I'm trying to accomplish is simply (in Python):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'([\w\']+|[.,;:?!])', 'This is starting to get really, really annoying!!')
['This', 'is', 'starting', 'to', 'get', 'really', ',', 'really', 'annoying', '!', '!']
```

The problem of the functions mentioned above is that either they return one match, or they return no match at all.

Comment: Wait, is it Python 3 or 2? `\w` has different default behaviors there.

Comment: It was Python 3, but I was trying to find a general solution to the problem, not necessarily to this specific regex.

Comment: Ok, I will add more to the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, there is no R exact equivalent to Python `re.findall` that either returns a list of match values or (a list of) tuples that hold capturing group submatches. The closest is `str_match_all` from the *stringr* package, but it is also very close to the Python `re.finditer` (as it returns the match value in the first item and then all submatches (capturing group contents) in the subsequent items (still not exact equivalent of `re.finditer` as only texts are returned, not match data objects)). So, if the whole match value was not returned with `str_match_all`, it would be an exact equivalent to Python `re.findall`.

You are using `re.findall` to just return *matches*, not captures, the capturing group in your pattern is redundant, and you may remove it. Thus, you can safely use `regmatches` with `gregexpr` and a PCRE flavor (since `[\\w']` won't work with a TRE regex):

```
s <- "This is starting to get really, really annoying!!"
res <- regmatches(s, gregexpr("[\\w']+|[.,;:?!]", s, perl=TRUE))
## => [[1]]
[1] "This"     "is"      "starting" "to"       "get"      "really"  
[7] ","        "really"   "annoying" "!"        "!"
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/Hzx4Tk)

Or, to make `\w` Unicode-aware, to make it work as in Python 3, add `(*UCP)` PCRE verb:

```
res <- regmatches(s, gregexpr("(*UCP)[\\w']+|[.,;:?!]", s, perl=TRUE))
```

See [another R demo](http://ideone.com/6ENiZ8)

If you want to use *stringr* package (that uses ICU regex library behind the scenes), you need `str_extract_all`:

```
res <- str_extract_all(s, "[\\w']+|[.,;:?!]")
```

Comment: Damn, `str_extract_all`, the only one I hadn't checked out... Thanks for the clarification on `\w` as well.