# R RegEx match n-th and m-th element of repeating capturing group

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to match specific elements of a repeating capturing group in a string in R. In this example the string contains a set of 3 numbers (optionally decimal or negative), which I can select individually with

```
> gsub(x = "-10.05 20 30.1 some information",
       pattern = "^((-?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)\\s){1}(.*)$",
       replacement = "\\2")
"-10.05"
```

by replacing the `{1}` part in the pattern with `{2}` or `{3}`.

In a more general case: Is there a way to simultaneously receive the n-th and m-th match? In this example maybe `{1}` and `{3}`?
Something like

```
> gsub(x = "-10.05 20 30.1 some information",
       pattern = "^((-?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)\\s){3}(.*)$",
       replacement = ...)
"-10.05 30.1"
```

where the `...` contains a specification of course.

Comment: Your pattern is off, you used a character class instead of a group, use `"^((-?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)\\s){3}(.*)$"`

Comment: There is no regex library that has a way to refer to a capture inside a group using a string backreference. So, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sufficient answer to my question can probably be adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401581/rs-equivalent-of-pythons-re-findall) already answered question. In my case it would have been something like the following:

```
> s <- "-10.05 20 30.1 some information"
> regmatches(s, gregexpr("(-?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?)", s, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "-10.05" "20"     "30.1"
```