# Regex to extract multiple numbers with decimal

Tags: python, regex, alteryx

**I have the following group of numbers**:

```
SalesCost% Margin
2,836,433.182,201,355.6422.39
```

**Expected Result**:

I want to separate this and extract the numbers such that I get the result as shown below:

```
2,836,433.18
2,201,355.64
22.39
```

**Attempt**

I tried the `(\d+)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?` regex but this only extracts the number until the first decimal, i.e. I only get `2,836,433.18`.

**Question**

Is there a way I can extract the numbers using Regex (or alternatively someway through Python) to get the results shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?', text)
re.findall(r'(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?', text)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/UPn53b/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/UPn53b/1).

*Details*:

- `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - zero or more occurrences of a comma and three digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of `.` and one or two digits.

The `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?` variation supports numbers like `123456.12`, i.e. no digit grouping symbol containing integer parts.

Comment: Dear Wiktor, may I ask what is the purpose of using non capturing group here?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Due to the fact `re.findall` returns (list of) tuples if a regex pattern contains a capturing group (groups) a non-capturing group is a common way to work around this problem. See [re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970). You may also be interested in [R's equivalent of Python's re.findall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401685/3832970).